# How to use SlimDX inside a WPF C# application

Tags: c#, slimdx

i'm totally new to SlimDX and WPF, but i need to create a multiple images in my application and one of them need to be a 3d visualizator of a point render, something like this:
http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5879/6a00d83452464869e2017ee.gif

I found i can use SlimDX to use DirectX by C# instruction in my application, writing the result in a D3DImage component.
After some tries i made visual studio 2012 to recoignize that D3DImage (for some reason i needed to restart windows to made it work) but i don't know a few things:

- How i can initialize a DirectX window inside that D3DImage? I really can't find any example or source code. All the examples i can find (like the 3 litte examples on SlimDX) are out of the WPF context
- Where i can find some good documentation about SlimDX? The GameDev community seems some kinda bugged and i can't post anything (maybe because i'm not paying) and i can't find anything anywhere! How i'm supposed to learn that?
- Not a single one of the SlimDX examples from the SVN can compile. I always got some reference error with the SlimDX library (empty path) and even re-importing from the correct path doesn't solve it

This is driving my crazy D:

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. I haven't be working to much with the D3D stuff in SlimDX for lack of a reason to do so, But I have been playing around with DirectSound and DirectInput, So i'll tell you what i've figured out.

First Bullet:
I'm not sure initializing a D3D Window inside of an image is going to work. If you're using Windows Forms as your base, SlimDX includes a RenderForm or some such thing that subclasses Windows.Forms, and provides a decent amount of functionality. I still haven't figured it out for WPF, even though there's supposed to be a sample for that.

Second Bullet: Documentation is difficult to come by. There's some stuff on the site, and some stuff here, but what's really been helpful is the MSDN Reference for DirectX. SlimDX Mirrors the structures pretty well, and you can find out a lot by reading it. It DOES take a bit of conversion, because the DirectX reference is C++.

Third Bullet: Same problem. Never was able to figure out why.

Hope that helps a bit.